# Android Retrofit - parsing JsonObejct and Array from same API call

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

Im calling API which can provide response sometimes as JsonObejct but sometimes as JsonArray. Is there any way to have retrofit prepeared for such situation? And for list it return list and for Json object it return jsut simple onject?

Thank you

Interface prepared for Array

```
interface ModelsApiInterface {
        @POST("/api/v4/dreambooth/model_list")
        fun sendReq(@Body requestModel: ModelsRequestModel) : Call<List<ModelsResponseModel>>
    }
```

Call

```
 val modelsRequestModel = ModelsRequestModel(
            API_KEY
        )
        val modelsResponse = ModelsServiceBuilder.buildService(ModelsApiInterface::class.java)
        modelsResponse.sendReq(modelsRequestModel).enqueue(
            object : Callback<List<ModelsResponseModel>> {
                override fun onResponse(calll: Call<List<ModelsResponseModel>>, response: Response<List<ModelsResponseModel>>) {
                    if (response.body()?.isNotEmpty()!!) {
                        val modelsList = mutableListOf<ModelsResponseModel>()
                        for (model in response.body()!!) {
                            modelsList.add(model)
                        }
                        createCarousel(modelsList)
                        generateViewModel.updateModelsData(modelsList)
                    }else if (response.body()?.get(0)?.status=="error"){
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error-Models\n${response.body()!!.get(0).message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
                override fun onFailure(calll: Call<List<ModelsResponseModel>>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("log", "failure-Models")
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "failure-Models", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }
            }
        )
```

My custom deserilalizer

```
 private class MyResponseDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<ModelsResponseModel?> {
        @Throws(JsonParseException::class)
        override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext
        ): ModelsResponseModel {
            var response = ModelsResponseModel(null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null)
            var list= mutableListOf<ModelsResponseModel>()
            if (json.isJsonObject) {
                var model_id:String = json.asJsonObject.get("model_id").asString
                var model_name:String = json.asJsonObject.get("model_name").asString
                var screenshots:String = json.asJsonObject.get("screenshots").asString
                var status = json.asJsonObject.get("status").asString

                response.status=status
                response.model_id=model_id
                response.model_name=model_name
                response.screenshots=screenshots
                return response
            }else if (json.isJsonArray){
                var model_id:String
                var model_name:String
                var screenshots:String

                for (item in json.asJsonArray){
                    model_id= item.asJsonObject.get("model_id").asString
                    model_name= item.asJsonObject.get("model_name").asString
                    screenshots= item.asJsonObject.get("screenshots").asString
                    list.add(ModelsResponseModel(null,null,null,model_id,model_name,screenshots,null,null))
                }
                return response
            }
            return response
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JsonElement`. It is the super class of both `JsonObject` and `JsonArray`. Then you can simply check and cast according to the type.